# Sort files with specific order

Tags: bash, ls

I have files like

```
file_fooX_barY_tests.txt
```

how can I list them in incremental after looping first on 'foo' and then looking in the number following 'bar' ? ie

```
file_foo100_bar1_test.txt
file_foo100_bar100_test.txt
file_foo100_bar150_test.txt
file_foo200_bar1_test.txt
file_foo200_bar100_test.txt
file_foo200_bar250_test.txt
```

doing a standard ls, list for example

```
file_foo100_bar100_test.txt
file_foo100_bar150_test.txt
file_foo100_bar1_test.txt
```

so, the 'bar100' and 'bar150' come before 'bar1'

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `sort -V` would do just the trick. It is meant to sort by "version order".

> Example :
>
> ```
> $ echo """file_foo100_bar150_test.txt
> file_foo100_bar1_test.txt
> file_foo200_bar250_test.txt
> file_foo200_bar100_test.txt
> file_foo200_bar1_test.txt
> file_foo100_bar100_test.txt
> """ | sort -V
>
> file_foo100_bar1_test.txt
> file_foo100_bar100_test.txt
> file_foo100_bar150_test.txt
> file_foo200_bar1_test.txt
> file_foo200_bar100_test.txt
> file_foo200_bar250_test.txt
> ```